# Add 2 chars without using strncpy?

Tags: c++, c

How would I manually concatenate two char arrays without using the `strncpy` function?

Can I just say `char1 + char2`?

Or would I have to write a `for` loop to get individual elements and add them like this:

```
addchar[0] = char1[0];
addchar[1] = char1[1];
etc
etc
addchar[n] = char2[0];
addchar[n+1] = char2[1];
etc
etc
```

To clarify, if
char1 = "happy"
char2 = "birthday"

I want addchar to = happybirthday

Comment: add two characters to what?  a string?  a char *?

Comment: To add two chars you'd cast one or the other to int, and then store the result in an int to avoid overflow, but I guess that's not the answer you're looking for. ie `char a = 'h', b = 'i'; int r = (int)a + b;`

Comment: Public service announcement: New users to a language often don't have the right vocabulary. Down voting the question because he didn't use the right language is... mean.

Comment: Why not use strncopy? What constraint might possibly place you in a position where you didn't want to use it? Are you programming hardware or is this homework?

Comment: Maybe he's programming on an embedded system without a full C/C++ runtime.

Comment: I agree with Frank Kreuger. The point here is that a char is a single character, such as "h", "a", "p", etc. The whole thing "happy" is called a *string*.

Comment: @Andreas Rijbrand: Actually, it's called a *character array*.  A "string" would be declared using `std::string`.

Comment: @bta: OK. I have never worked much with C/C++. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider two trivial loops to be "manual", then yes, without using the standard library this is the only way.

```
char *append(const char *a, const char *b) {
    int i = 0;
    size_t na = strlen(a);
    size_t nb = strlen(b);
    char *r = (char*)calloc(na + nb + 1, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
        r[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        r[na + i] = b[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

Remember to call `free`.

Comment: It would be better (and more consistent with the standard library) if the caller supplied an already-allocated destination buffer (along with its size). It is good practice that the one responsible for freeing memory is the one responsible for allocating it.

Comment: "Foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds." Just kidding, just kidding! But honestly, the design of the standard library seems to have favored CPU productivity over human. I do not like its interfaces and choose not to propagate them. (Except, `atoi`, that function is OK.)

Comment: C and its standard library were developed in the 70's/80's when resources were constrained. C's current niche is still in resource-constrained environments. If human productivity is of utmost concern, then there are other languages that are more appropriate than C.

Answer (score 4):

For a C-only solution use [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/):

```
char destination[80] = "";
char string1[] = "Hello";
char string2[] = " World!";


/* Copy string1 to destination */
strncat(destination, string1, sizeof(destination));

/* Append string2 to destination */
strncat(destination, string2, sizeof(destination) - sizeof(string1));
```

Note that the strn* family of string functions are safer than the ones without n, because they avoid the possibility of buffer overruns.

For a C++ solution, simply use std::string and operator+ or operator+=:

```
std::string destination("Hello ");
destination += "World";
destination += '!';
```

Comment: Edited to avoid using strncpy. Do you want to avoid string functions altogether? If so, please indicate in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using c++ just use an `std::string`.  With `std::string`s, the `+` operator is supported, so you can do string1+string2.

Answer (score 1):

Without using library functions, here is the procedure:
1.  Point to the first character in string1.
2.  While the current character at the pointer is not null, increment the pointer.
3.  Create a "source" pointer pointing to string2.
4.  While the character at the "source" location is not null:
4.1.  Copy the character from the "source" location to the location pointed to by the String1 pointer.
4.2.  Increment both pointers.

Unless this is homework, use C++ `std::string` for your text.
If you must use C style strings, use the library functions.
Library functions are optimized and validated, reducing your development time.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you want something like this:

```
char1 + char2
```

First, let's see the insane solution:

C:

```
char* StringAdd(char* a_Left, char* a_Right)
{
    unsigned int length_left = strlen(a_Left);
    unsigned int length_right = strlen(a_Right);
    unsigned int length = length_left + length_right;

    char* result = (char*)malloc(length);

    // clear the string
    memset(result, 0, length);

    // copy the left part to the final string
    memcpy(result, a_Left, length_left);

    // append the right part the to the final string
    memcpy(&result[length_left], a_Right, length_right);

    // make sure the string actually ends
    result[length] = 0;

    return result;
}
```

C++:

```
char* StringAdd(char* a_Left, char* a_Right)
{
    unsigned int length_left = strlen(a_Left);
    unsigned int length_right = strlen(a_Right);
    unsigned int length = length_left + length_right;

    char* result = new char[length];

    // clear the string
    memset(result, 0, length);

    // copy the left part to the final string
    memcpy(result, a_Left, length_left);

    // append the right part the to the final string
    memcpy(&result[length_left], a_Right, length_right);

    // make sure the string actually ends
    result[length] = 0;

    return result;
}
```

Now, let's see the sane solution:

```
char* StringAdd(char* a_Left, char* a_Right)
{
    unsigned int length = strlen(a_Left) + strlen(a_Right);

    char* result = new char[length];
    strcpy(result, a_Left);
    strcat(result, a_Right);

    return result;
}
```

So, was this homework? I don't really care.

If it was, ask yourself: what did you learn?

Comment: You have a buffer overflow bug.

Comment: I could say I left it as an exercise to the reader, but I'd be lying.